# errors after compiling the decompiled code in jetbrains dotpeek software

Tags: c#, web-services

i have decompiled my dotnet code via dotpeek software. but , when tries to compile it again , it gives a lots of error. i am failing to remove this error

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\WebServices.asmx.cs(408): Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool
```

the source of error is here:

```
this.WriteLog("Flag3: " + (object) (bool) (flag2 ? 1 : 0));
```

i am also not understanding this `(flag2 ? 1 : 0)`

can , anyone tell what is meaning of this.waiting for your responses.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the code that is output from dotPeek is compilable or even makes sense in all cases. The code you've posted is an example. Try just: `("Flag3: " + flag2)`

Comment: Why are you decompiling your assemblies in the first place, why aren't you simply editing the original source code? Did you lose it? If so I would recommend starting to use a version control system that is hosted in the cloud, like bitbucket, github, kiln, etc.

Comment: hi @Lasse V. Karlsen first thanks for informationand i dont have updated original source code, currently i have removed the bugs,i am also success to compile the code again.i am not aware from version control system . can , it provides me to origional code runnig on server?please guide.

Comment: The point of version control systems, and backups in general, is that they store the original code, and all the changes that happen over time. The *only* reason you should have to decompile something is to look at other peoples code. To look at *your own code* you go to the original code, which you should make sure to keep a copy of.

Comment: is , it same as svn. svn also take projects copies but the thing is that when the last updation made, the code was not commited into svn. therefore i am in trouble.